# Is there a more efficient way to use for loops?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am making a room booking program and I have got the following code:

```
    def book_clicked(self):
        self._checked_items = []
        for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                item = self.tableWidget.item(i, j)
                if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                    self.v = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(j).text()
                    self.h = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(i).text()
                    self._checked_items.append([self.h, self.v, self.tableWidget.item(i, j).text()])

    def addBooking(self):
        now = QDate.currentDate()
        now1 = now.toString(Qt.DefaultLocaleLongDate)
        room,lesson,irr = zip(*self._checked_items)
        connection = sqlite3.connect("roombooking.db")
        c = connection.cursor()

        idLb = connection.execute("SELECT bookingID,lessonBooked FROM Booking WHERE dateBooked = ?",([now1]))
        idLb = idLb.fetchall()
        bID, lesBk = zip(*idLb)
        rm = connection.execute("SELECT roomNO FROM BookedRoom WHERE bookingID = ?",([bID[0]]))
        rm = rm.fetchall()
        for rooms in rm:
            print (rooms)
            if rooms == room:
                #This checks to see if the rooms in the BookedRoom table match the room that user has chosen
                for lessons in lesBk:
                    #This gets all the lessonsBooked for todays date
                    for lesson1 in lesson:
                        #This gets all the lessons that the user wants to book
                        if lessons == lesson1:
                            #If any of them match then the error shows
                            self.bookError = Ui_Dialog1()
                            self.bookError.show()
                        else:
                            ## Allow Booking ##
                            # Insert into Booking table #
                            lastBookingId = []
                            print ("Allow Booking")
                            for item in lesson:
                                c.execute("INSERT INTO Booking (lessonBooked, dateBooked, username) VALUES (?,?,?)",(item,now1,self.username))
                                connection.commit()
                                lastBookingId.append (c.lastrowid)
                            # Insert into BookedRoom table #
                            for i in range (len (lastBookingId)):
                                roomb = room[i]
                                lastBookingId1 = lastBookingId[i]
                                print (roomb)
                                print (lastBookingId1)
                                c.execute ("INSERT INTO BookedRoom (roomNO, bookingID) VALUES (?, ?)",(roomb,lastBookingId1))
                                connection.commit()

            else:
                ## Allow Booking ##
```

Variables:

- room - stores the room number(s) the user wants to book.
- lesson - stores the lesson time(s) they want to book.

What I want this code to do is check if the room and time that the user is trying to book is already in the database, if it is then the error window will open. However I feel that this is an ineffective way of doing this since I use so many for loops to loop through the lists. Also I want want the program to allow the user to book the room (adding it to the db) if the room and lesson time combination is not in the database. So I do this in the else statements however this causes the program to allow the user to book rooms that are already in the database multiple times as seen in the output:

[image: Output]

I am not sure what exactly is causing this but I have a feeling it is the way I have coded the for loops.

roombooking.db:

```
def create_user_table():
    sql = """create table User
             (username text,
             password text,
             teacher bit,
             primary key(username))"""
    create_table(db_name,"User", sql)

def create_booking_table():
    sql = """create table Booking
             (bookingID integer,
             lessonBooked text,
             dateBooked text,
             username text,
             primary key(bookingID)
             foreign key(username) references User(username))"""    
    create_table(db_name,"Booking", sql)

def create_room_table():
    sql = """create table Room
             (roomNO text,
             location text,
             roomType text,
             primary key(roomNO))"""    
    create_table(db_name,"Room", sql)

def create_bookedroom_table():
    sql = """create table BookedRoom
             (roomNO text,
             bookingID integer,
             primary key(roomNO, bookingID) 
             foreign key(roomNO) references Room(roomNO)
             foreign key(bookingID) references Booking(bookingID))"""
    create_table(db_name,"BookedRoom", sql)
```

Comment: share your .roombooking.db

Comment: @eyllanesc I have added this.

Comment: what is `_checked_items`? provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc it is a list which stores the row and column header of the checkboxes that have been checked in a table

Comment: I'm interested in not knowing the source but the data itself because you need to analyze what is doing your logic, for me it would be easier if you share your project via github, drive, dropbox, etc.

Comment: @eyllanesc https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_roOUoFygrlttl_7Y1jYHeqAaRcyWknl?usp=sharing - The main file is called EPHS_RoomBooking_Map

Comment: What is the procedure that I must follow to execute the code that you indicate? I have run EPHS_RoomBooking_Map.py where a login window appears where I enter the credentials correctly and a window appears where I can select the floors and search for each room, but I do not know what to press or what procedure to follow to run addBooking.

Comment: @eyllanesc the details you want to enter are username - klange, password - azaz, sorry should've specified since my program splits into 2 depending on which type of user is using the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not going to rewrite your code but ill give you some generic advice on solving this

1. If they will be small lists you are looping over then store them independently as list and dictionaries
2. Learn about list comprehension. It calls compiled code under the hood so will be faster. Will work for dictionaries.
3. Break your code into several methods and have no more than one loop per method.